# UDP: Streaming desktop ffmpeg over Wide area network

Tags: video, networking, ffmpeg, udp

I am using ffmpeg to stream my desktop. It works perfectly over the LAN with two connected PCs; however, over a WAN, the reciever gets unviewable shearing and tearing of the desktop. We figured it was because the LAN has a 5 MB/s bandwith and the WAN has a bandwidth limitation 1 MB/s. When I checked the ethernet output of the sending PC, the bandwidth was 1 MB/s +/- .02.

The original ffmpeg script I used was within a batch file was:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="screen-capture-recorder"-vcodec
libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -tune zerolatency -r 30 -b:v 750k -minrate 750k -maxrate 750k  -f mpegts udp://ip:port
```

On the reciever side:
1. I opened the scream capture recorder GUI.
2. Inserted the appropriate udp address.
3. Hit "Start Recieving".

I did a wireshark analysis and noticed most of the packets I saw were MPEG TS packets with  had "MP2T fragment of a reassembled package" in the description column.

My question is: has anyone been able to successful stream via ffmpeg over a wide area network with no issues of the recieving video? If so, what ffmpeg parameters did you use for consistent results?

Comment: Not sure if this will fix it, but you can try to set the udp packet size like udp://ip:port?pkt_size=1316

Comment: Flagged as should be closed because there is now a dedicated ffmpeg section: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffmpeg